# Cannot find libmysql.dll when building Qt statically

Tags: mysql, qt, dll, static

A have compiled Qt with -static option and with -qt-sql-mysql. Everything goes well (compilation etc, it works on my computer). But when I put the program on the other computer I get the message "Cannot find libmysql.dll...". And nothing else happens.

Answer (score 0):

Statically linked Qt doesn't mean that the sql plugins will use the static database libraries. You'd need to set the path to the mysql library such that a static library would be used. As it is, you're using a so-called export mysql library.

The immediate solution to get your program running is to include `libmysql.dll` in the installation path of your program.

The long-term solution is to reconfigure your Qt build with the correct, static mysql library, and rebuild the plug-in. You need to point `configure` to the right variant of the library. You can have a `.lib` file that is a static library, and another `.lib` file that is the import library. The former will be larger, and that's the one you want. The latter will make your executable dependent on `mysql.dll`.

The mysql C connector library is built as a dynamic library by default. You'd have to build it manually as a static library. It requires some [tweaking of the cmakefile](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/documentation.html), IIRC. I haven't done it in a while. The general instructions are [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connector-c-installation-source.html#connector-c-build-options) but again, there's no ready-to-go static library option.

Comment: I have used option -qt-sql-mysql together with -static flag. I thought that it is non-plugin version as it was written in configure help.

Comment: @FilipPost: You can have a static plugin that links with a dynamic mysql library, and that's precisely what you got.

Comment: So how can I get static mysql library?